# How does Pythons double-sided inequality work? and why doesn't it work for numpy arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, comparison, operators, boolean-expression

In Python you can do the following;

```
>>> 3 < 4 < 5
True
>>> 3 < 4 < 4
False
```

How does this work? I would have thought that `4 < 5` would return a boolean, and so `3 < True` should return `False`, or `3 < 4` should return a boolean and so `True < 4` should maybe return `True` if `True` could be cast as an integer 1?.

And why doesn't it work for numpy arrays?

```
>>> 1 < np.array([1, 2, 3]) < 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Could it be made to work for numpy arrays?

Comment: It's evaluated as `3 < 4 and 4 < 5`. Also, the numpy error you're receiving has nothing to do with the fact that you are chaining the operators together. Rather, it has to do with the fact that the truthy-ness of a numpy array with more than one value is ambiguous, as the error message says. You would have gotten the same error if you simply did `bool(np.array([1, 2, 3]))`.

Comment: @PaulM. Why doesn't it work for numpy arrays then?

```
1 < np.array([1, 2, 3]) and np.array([1, 2, 3]) < 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```
Then why shouldn't I be able to do;
```
np.array([1]) < np.array([1, 2, 3]) < np.array([3])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: FYI this feature has been around since at least [2.7](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#comparisons), which is now EOL, so I removed that bit of the question since it's not really important.

Comment: @wjandrea okay my bad, thanks for the edit.

Comment: @PaulM. - your rewrite isn't correct, as you are applying `all()` to the original numpy array rather than to the result of comparing it to an integer.  A simplification of your rewrite is `0 < True < 5`, which obviously isn't useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons):

> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., `x < y <= z` is equivalent to `x < y and y <= z`, except that `y` is evaluated only once (but in both cases `z` is not evaluated at all when `x < y` is found to be false).

So your example is equivalent to:

```
1 < np.array([1, 2, 3]) and np.array([1, 2, 3]) < 3
```

so each subterm is expected to result in a boolean value.  But the subterm:

```
1 < np.array([1, 2, 3])
```

results in a new numpy array containing:

```
[False, True, True]
```

It is this value that Python is trying to interpret as a boolean value.  It fails to do that, producing the error message:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I expect that the desired expression here is:

```
(1 < np.array([1, 2, 3])).all() and (np.array([1, 2, 3]) < 3).all()
```

which can't be simplified to use comparison chaining.

Comment: It's that `evaluated only once` that make the double sided expression special. Otherwise it's just a syntactic shortcut.  So having to use two separate comparisons in `numpy` is no great loss.  Since `numpy` comparisons are element-wise, you have choices to make when making logical combinations.

Comment: @hpaulj - I don't disagree with anything you're saying.  A more equivalent expression in terms of efficiency or even function might involve extracting the creation of the numpy array to a separate function such that it only happens once.  I was just answering the "why" question, which didn't require getting into that subtlety.  Given the existence of `[1, 2, 3]` in the expression in question, this clearly is not produciton code.

Comment: I should have indicated that my comment was directed more at the OP than you.  I assume the OP is notified of comments in answers, so didn't try to add an `@`.

Comment: @hpaulj - ah.  makes sense.  sorry I took that as directed towards me.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do this and came up with the following possibly suboptimal solution.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(20)
(a > 3).__and__(a < 15)
```

This gives the answer I wanted from `3 < a < 15`.